# Swirl does not install on R 4.0.0

Tags: r, swirl, r-4.0

I've been trying to install the SWIRL package on R 4.0.0 on RStudio Desktop 1.2.5042 on windows using install.packages("swirl"). The installation fails and I get the following error message:

"Error in readRDS(pfile) : 
  cannot read workspace version 3 written by R 4.0.0; need R 3.5.0 or newer"

Does anyone know if this is a solvable error? Will I have to wait until a new version of SWIRL comes out?

Comment: Who or what is issueing that error?  Looks like a faulty version comparison as 4.0.0 is newer than 3.5.0, and using R correctly (i.e. `package_version("4.0.0") > package_version("3.5.0")`) shows it.  If it is in the package you could download the source, edit out the test and install the modified version.

Comment: I think it's a problem with RStudio because when I tried doing the same thing on RGUI it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the changes in R version 4.0.0

Defunct functions mem.limits(), .readRDS(), .saveRDS(),..find.package(), and .path.package() from package base

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html

I also use a lot RDS fuctions